# Unable to get Shopify fulfillment_order_id via REST API

Tags: rest, shopify

I'm trying to get the `fulfillment_order_id` for my order in Python by using `requests.get(url)` with the following URL: `f"https://redacted.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/orders/{order_id}/fulfillment_orders.json"`.

The order_id I use was extracted from a separate request to the endpoint `https://redacted.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-01/orders.json?limit=250`. Here I find the relevant order from the list and fetch the value of the `id` field, in my example `4754292932796`.

This order ID lets me successfully fulfill the order via the now-deprecated `2021-07` method of using the `fulfillments.json` endpoint - so it seems to be valid.

However, when I try to perform the above request to get the `fulfillment_order_id` I get {'fulfillment_orders': []} - the same response I get if I perform the request with a random order ID.

Am I supposed to use some other ID in the request?